# JQueryMobile: Changes html-input-type to 'number' at runtime?

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I am trying to make a JQuery-mobil app + Android with a WebView.

The app has a `html-input` wich by default is set to `type="text"`
if a end user press the input then the standart Android-keybord popup.

Like this:

[image]

**This is ok**

**But** I need a button there changes `type` to `type="number"` so on press the keybord only shows numbers.

Like this:

[image]

This is the HTML I use for this:

```
/*html-input*/
<input type="text" name="regnr" value=""/>

/*Open keybord as number-keybord: </label>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" id="keybord-as-numbers">Number</a>
```

This JQuery-script use `replaceWith` for replace input-tag on button-click, so type is set to number

```
<script>
$(function(){
    //onClick: keybord-as-numbers
    $("#keybord-as-numbers").click(function(){
        $("#regnr").replaceWith("");
        $("#div-searchnumber").html('<input type="number" class="searchnumber" data-icon="search" name="regnr" maxlength="4" id="regnr" value="" data-inline="true" autofocus /\>');
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is it remove the css-style and I can´t `.get` the value from the `html-input`,
after the `replaceWith` function is don.

I has try with `$('#regnr').attr('type', 'number');` but this do not look like this works :(

Comment: Android's input type has not been the most consistent implementation.  In your case, maybe you are better off having two input controls, and show and hide them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

And you can simply change your class id and have this code on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".numeric").numeric();
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you could write your own function and call it onkeyup event

See: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_158.html

Another option is using step attribute:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.step.float

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" >
```

Comment: hmm the .numeric() do not open the keybord on my HTC desire, I will try to do as Tianzhen Lin says!